# How to redirect entire wordpress folder with dynamic URLs to a single page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, dynamic

I had old wordpress blog which was under mywebsite.com/wordpress

Now I have moved this blog but I would like to redirect the entire wordpress folder to a single category page mywebsite.com/category/test

The problem is that I don't know how to redirect dynamic pages (all at once) such as 

wordpress/?p=1

wordpress/?p=2

wordrpess/?page_id=1362

and others.

I don't need a page to page redirect, just an entire redirect from the wordpress folder to one single category page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have used the .htaccess tag, so assume you have access to an .htaccess file.

Try this in .htaccess in the root of your website:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^facts/(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/category/test/ [R=permanent,L]
```

Let us know if that works!

EDIT: Add a ? to the end of the destination rule to strip the querystring info:

```
RewriteRule ^facts/(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/category/test/? [R=permanent,L]
```

Ben

Comment: Now we are getting closer :) 
It redirects from
http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?p=3139
to
http://ubuntulife.net/category/ubuntu/?p=3139
But how to redirect all the pages from "/wordpress/" to a single category page?

Comment: @Aigars Ok, I've added to the answer. You can add a ? to remove the querystring info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that there's an option under dashboard-->settings-->general (maybe?) that allows you to designate your landing page! and that should redirect your site to that category page....

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Old website is already moved elsewhere so I want to get rid of those 404 errors popping up each time someone is trying to access these pages. I need a simple htaccess redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In `.htacess` file To redirect the page

```
Redirect /themes_name/your_file.php /themes_name/your_file.php
```

First your old blog file path and second new blog file path